# How do I use the kpse library to get the value of $TEXMFHOME?

Tags: luatex, distributions

Inspired by [some recent experiments on the subject](http://www.texdev.net/2014/05/25/lua-for-latex3-build-scripts/), I'm trying to use `texlua` to automate the installation, done by multiple users, of a complex environment (multiple packages, classes and formats) on multiple computers running different OS and different distribution (TeXLive, MikTeX and MacTeX). `LuaTeX` appears to be the only program I can rely on to work in such conditions.

I need to copy some files somewhere in the `$TEXMFHOME` directory. So, I tried the following to print the local `$TEXMFHOME` path:

```
-- this is file texlua-file.lua
local kpse = require('kpse')
kpse.set_program_name('texlua-file.lua')
print(kpse.expand_var('$TEXMFHOME'))
```

Run with `texlua` from `/home/christophe/sandbox/lua`, it gives me the following:

```
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /home/christophe/sandbox/lua:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/share/texmf/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/lua/texmf/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox:/home/christophe/sandbox/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/share/texmf/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/sandbox/texmf/web2c:/home/christophe/../texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe:/home/christophe/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/share/texmf/web2c:/home/christophe/texmf-local/web2c:/home/christophe/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/christophe/texmf/web2c.
$TEXMFHOME
```

Besides I don't understand the need stated in the `LuaTeX` documentation for the line

```
kpse.set_program_name("texlua-file.lua")
```

how can I tell `kpse` where to look for the `texmf.cnf` file without knowing the actual settings of the local TeX distribution?

Comment: `kpse.set_program_name('texlua')`

Comment: @egreg It works! Thanks. I really don't understand that part of the doc: "Second, in `TEXLUA` mode, the initialization has to be done explicitly via the `kpse.set_program_name function`, which sets the `KPATHSEA` executable (and optionally program) name." So the `KPATHSEA` executable is `texlua`? BTW, can you turn your comment to an answer to that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kpse variables such as `TEXMFHOME` or `TEXINPUTS` are not usually set in the environment, but are assigned a value at runtime, based on reading the configuration files named `texmf.cnf` with a certain order (see kpathsea documentation).

However, the Lua system embedded in LuaTeX doesn't use the library by default (the TeX part does). It can, however, load the `kpse` Lua library for querying kpse. This must however be initialized with some engine as argument to `kpse.set_program_name` because the kpse variables can be assigned different values according to the engine used; for instance, running `texlua` on

```
local kpse = require('kpse')
kpse.set_program_name('pdftex')
print(kpse.expand_var('$TEXMFHOME'))
print(kpse.expand_var('$TEXINPUTS'))
```

produces, on my system,

```
/Users/enrico/Library/texmf
.:{/Users/enrico/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-config,/Users/enrico/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-var,/Users/enrico/Library/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist}/tex/{plain,generic,}//
```

while changing `pdftex` into `pdflatex` outputs

```
/Users/enrico/Library/texmf
.:{/Users/enrico/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-config,/Users/enrico/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-var,/Users/enrico/Library/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist}/tex/{latex,generic,}//
```

Thus one can adapt the usage of `kpse.expand_var()` to different engines.

Note: I produced the output running a shell where the development version of TeX Live is used, which explains the 2014 bits.